# error using cfkeditor in coldfusion

Tags: coldfusion

I m using below for cfkeditor in coldfusion. but it throws error.

```
<cfmodule
template="/fckeditor/fckeditor.cfm"
basePath="/fckeditor/"
instanceName="WebPage"
value=''
width="650"
height="360">
```

Answer (score 2):

Your issue is likely that you don't need the leading `/`

```
<cfmodule
template="fckeditor/fckeditor.cfm"
basePath="fckeditor/"
instanceName="WebPage"
value=''
width="650"
height="360">
```